# Plots not visible within markdown and bootstrap navtabs

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap-3, rstudio, r-markdown

I want to use navtabs from the bootstrap packages from within RStudio. I would like show plots within a nav tab. However the result I get is:

[image: results]
[image]

It seems to me, as a non html expert, that the png files can not be found because they are not rendered or have a wrong path.

How can make sure that the plots are shown in final html page?

````
---
output: html_document
---



<!--html_preserve-->
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
  </ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="A">
```{r a, echo = F}
plot(1,2)
```
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="B">
```{r b, echo = F}
plot(2,1)
```               
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--/html_preserve-->
````

Comment: it seems to me that your code expects that these plots are saved somewhere. is this the case? simply calling plot() will not do that for you.

Comment: to save plots with RStudio you have to use this http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html or use the export functionality (I recommend the png() function)

Answer (score 0):

It works by using `<!--html_preserve-->`

````
---
output: html_document
---


<!--html_preserve-->
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="A">
<!--/html_preserve-->
```{r a, echo = F}
plot(1,2)
```
<!--html_preserve-->
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="B">
<!--/html_preserve-->
```{r b, echo = F}
plot(2,1)
```          
<!--html_preserve-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/html_preserve-->
````